# x-axis based on two dimensions (or groups)?

Tags: graph, gnumeric

Is there a way to define a x-axis based on two dimensions (or groups)? For instance, I have a first dimension groups with the names "linord-rd", "linord-rs", and "linord-reg". Now I want a second dimension granuality with values 3, 6, 9, and 12.
For each combination of groups and granuality I would like to plot a box plot. So it should look like

```
-------------------------------------------
|     box plots for each combination      |
-------------------------------------------
| lo-rd lo-rs lo-reg | lo-rd lo-rs lo-reg |
-------------------------------------------
|         3          |         6          |
-------------------------------------------
```

and so on. Sorry for the bad visualization. Hope you get the point.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not currently possible, unfortunately, at least not easily. There are plans to implement support for that feature, but it's not trivial, and we lack developer time.
May be you can add a second axis and a second box plot with less series (with just one 0 as datum for its series so that nothing is displayed except the labels) I joins a sample of what I could do (with random values). Hope this helps. 
[image]

Comment: Thanks for your help. Your example looks really good and I will try to do it that way. I find gnumeric very intuitive and well-featured for my needs. Great work!